# Detect div position with in parent div with scrollTop

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

I want to detect with scrollTop the position of a div within a parent div (e.g #content) (e.g with .row) and apply a class to this .row (as there are many divs with class row it has to apply a class to the div that's is with x pixels from the bottom.

I tried to apply to all class with .row and worked fine, but can't get it to apply to the dives (with .row) that fit the if parameters.

```
$(function(){
  if ($(".row").offset().top > ($("#content").scrollTop() + $("#content").height() - 40)) {
    $(this).addClass("above-popup");
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't you do "child.scrollTop - parent.scrollTop"?

Comment: `$(".row").offset().top` will always give you the value of the first element (with index zero) of the collection. To check for all `.row` you'd need to loop through them - `.each()` is useful for this. Or if you know the index of the element you want to target, you could also use `$(".row").eq(index)`.